# Setting or reading the recovery email address in Gmail programmatically

Tags: ruby, oauth, gmail, oauth-2.0

Is it possible to read or set the recovery email address in Gmail programmatically? 
For example via OAuth.

I need to do this for a web app in Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it via web page requests, using a gem e.g. mechanize or system tool e.g. curl.

https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6566

As far as I know, there's no API way to change it for a normal gmail user.

Google Apps users may have additional capabilities, and so do Google Apps admins, and if you're able to use these then read about admins and provisioning here:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/email-settings/?hl=en

Retrieving the domain administrator's secondary email address is possible via HTTP:

http://code.google.com/apis/apps/admin_settings/docs/1.0/admin_settings_developers_guide_protocol.html#RetrievingAdminSecondEmail

So is changing the domain administrator's secondary email address; see the same link above.

Comment: thank you - for normal Gmail, is there a Ruby gem you advise using for web page requests?

Comment: or some basic examples I could understand and modify (I'm a beginner)

Comment: Yes, the ruby-gmail gem is good for signing in, retrieving mail, etc.

Comment: To automate the web page browsing to do the get/set of the recovery email, I suggest mechanize.